# CUDA error: all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable

Tags: nvidia, gpu, pytorch

мои параметры
NVIDIA gtx1050
linux mint
При повторном прогоне сети выдается ошибка, что видеокарта занята, хотя в jupyter notebook отображается, что она свободна
`torch.cuda.is_available() True torch.cuda.current_device() 0`

При наборе в консоли
nvidia-smi
отображаются процессы, однако вроде бы ни чем видеокарта не загружена (кроме 1041мб памяти, выделенной на прошлый прогон сети)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данная проблема лечится только перезагрузкой ПК, однако это не выглядит как хороший вариант.
Может быть у кого-то есть решения для данной проблемы?